# Use the wordpress admin table

Tags: admin

I want to create a custom page, which uses the GUI from wordpress, so I don't have to use my own. I want to take the table from wordpress posts and using to display my own information (hidden custom post or any other database)

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include and extend the WP_List_Table class
`class Example_List_Table extends WP_List_Table`

Best way to learn this is to modify the custom list table plugin: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-list-table-example/

For a full tutorial check this out: 
https://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp_list_table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/

And read the codex here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table